# TypeError: schema is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = mongoose.schema;

const marioCharSchema = new schema({

    name: String,
    weight: Number

});

const marioChar = mongoose.model('marioChar', marioCharSchema);

module.exports = marioChar;
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, welcome to StackOverflow. What's your question? Also, please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Typo. It's `mongoose.Schema`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on second line use
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
javascript is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 0):

Just export as an object and require on your test as object as well. Like this:

```
module.exports = {MarioChar};

const assert = require('assert');
const {MarioChar} = require('../models/mariochar');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

The wrong was in the case.